# Excel ─ Phone # formatting issue

Tags: excel, format

How can I convert numbers into phone numbers, knowing they have different character length ? For example:

I have

- 49123456789
- 4912345678912
- 491234567891234

And I want them to be

- +49 12 345 67 89
- +49 12 345 67 8912
- +49 12 345 67 891234

In other words, **I want only the beginning of numbers** to be formatted*, because each phone number has its own extension, which can have different lengths... (I hope this can be solved *via* simple format code and not by complex VBA)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated !
Thanks

**Specifically, I only want the first 9 numbers formatted, and the remaining numbers (IF there are any) to be simply added next to it.*

Comment: do you have less than 9 numbers?

Comment: I don't have this list, why ? And no, I have 9 to 13 digits for each number

Answer (score 1):

If your number is in `A1`, how's this?

`="+"&LEFT(A1,2)&" "&MID(A1,3,2)&" "&MID(A1,5,3)&" "&MID(A1,8,2)&" "&MID(A1,10,LEN(A1)-9)`

It works for your examples, but is obviously more "brute force" than elegant, but let me know if it doesn't work for all numbers.

Edit: If you want a little more compact/pretty formula, use @pnuts' suggestion below.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following formula, F1 is your initial number:

```
=IF(LEN(F1)>9,TEXT(LEFT(F1,9),"+## ## ### ##")&" "&MID(F1,10,LEN(F1)-9),TEXT(F1,"+## ## ### ##"))
```

The formula test the length of the number if >9 the function Text will transform the first 9 digit with the format "+## ## ### ##" and the rest normal " "&rest 
if =9 the format is "+## ## ### ##"

Comment: Thank you for your input @yass :)

Comment: Did you try any?